# Using union types with flow sensitivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

I'm trying to use union types with `is_a?` for flow control, but I'm still getting sorbet errors. I've tried casting as well, and I'm still running into the same error, which is:

`Method to_hash does not exist on T::Array[T.untyped] component of T.any(T::Array[T.untyped], T::Hash[Symbol, T.untyped]) https://srb.help/7003`

I have the following struct:

```
  class PostProcessingMethod < T::Struct
    prop :method_name, Symbol
    prop :args, T.any(Array, T::Hash[Symbol, T.untyped]), default: []
    prop :changed_fields, T::Array[String], default: []
    prop :all, T::Boolean, default: false
    prop :force, T::Boolean, default: false
  end
```

and I'm using it in a method that (currently) looks like this:

```
    sig { params(post_processing_methods: T::Array[Documents::PostProcessingMethod]).void }
    def call(post_processing_methods)
      post_processing_methods.each do |post_processing_method|
        next unless should_call_method?(post_processing_method)

        if @object.respond_to?(post_processing_method.method_name)
          if post_processing_method.args.is_a?(Array)
            @object.send(post_processing_method.method_name, *post_processing_method.args)
          elsif post_processing_method.args.is_a?(Hash)
            @object.send(post_processing_method.method_name, **post_processing_method.args)
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

I've tried incorporating `T.cast` to ensure that sorbet knows it's a Hash in the elsif, but that doesn't seem to have made a difference.

My expectation is that `is_a?` should allow sorbet to know that `post_processing_method` is a `Hash` in the `elseif`. But if that's not the case, the `T.cast` should certainly handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code posted, each `.args` call is treated like a new variable. If you capture the returning value in a local variable, the flow sensitivity will work.

See an example on [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/ace/#extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20returns(T.any(Hash%2C%20Array))%20%7D%0Adef%20get_args%0A%20%20return%20T.unsafe(nil)%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20doesnt%20work%0Aif%20get_args.is_a%3F(Hash)%0A%20%20get_args.to_hash%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20this%20works%0Aargs%20%3D%20get_args%0Aif%20args.is_a%3F(Hash)%0A%20%20args.to_hash%0Aend%0A%0A)